# Debugging taking a lot of time?

Tags: anti-virus, performance, visual-studio, debug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

hi,
   yesterday i install visual studio in my system, when i run my application it is taking a lot of time to run my application, i think it is due to virus. can u please tell me which is the best anti-virus in the market present. so that i can run my visual studio easily.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "taking a long time"? Long time to do what? Which version of Visual Studio is this?  
  
One common issue is if you are loading your website in Firefox, it will load the page extremely slow until you turn off ipv6 in about:config

Comment: Mr.Matt  i6 is my browser and visual studio 2005. i write a simple code just displaying a message, it is taking so much time i thought it is virus problem.

Comment: Visual Studio is slow. It's most likely not due to a virus, or else you'd probably be experiencing other symptoms.

Comment: Show us your code and tell us how long it takes to run, in seconds.

Comment: "Best free antivirus for Windows" question: http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows

Comment: Though even if it was his wish to know for best antivirus, I doubt the cause of his debugging being slow was because of it. But I guess he will ask another question then.

Comment: while generally [the "duplicate" question](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware) is not meant to be an end-all-be-all virus question, this question is old and apparently abandoned.  closing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is truly a virus, I like [Eset Nod32](http://www.eset.com/) because of it's [scoring](http://www.eset.com/products/compare-NOD32-vs-competition.php).  I'm not sure if the online scanners will find a virus using rootkit technology, but Eset (and many others) have [free online scanners](http://www.eset.com/onlinescan/).

Other free online anti-virus scanners:
[Trend Micro](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/)
[Norton Anti-virus](http://security.symantec.com/sscv6/WelcomePage.asp)

If you search for free online scanners and stick to the major name brands you will find a few.  If you want, you can run two or three and if they don't find anything, either your in the clear or you have a deeper problem (rootkit).

There were some free rootkit detectors, one you may want to run is [Microsoft RootkitRevealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx).

Hopefully, the slowness is just a sign of slow hardware, or visual studio spinning up your app or running your app in debug mode.  While that won't speed things up, but it's better than having a virus.

Good luck.